# Cant get async and await to work correctly

Tags: react-native, async-await, axios

I am trying to make a login/create account screen but I can't get my async to work properly.  Await is not working my console prints out undefinded when right after it calls the authToken and then it prints the 'About to call saveUserToken'.

I call this after I click the create account button.

```
async createUser() { 
        if ((this.state.email != "" && this.state.fname != "" && this.state.lname != "" && this.state.password != "" && this.state.confirmPassword != "")) {
            if (this.state.password == this.state.confirmPassword) {

                const authToken = await QueryHandler.createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.fname, this.state.lname);
                console.log(authToken);

                console.log('About to call saveUserToken');
                const storeToken = await SecureDataStorage.saveUserToken(authToken);
                console.log(storeToken);

                ToastHandler.displayNormalMessage('Stored Token');
                const t = await SecureDataStorage.getUserToken();
                console.log('Got from SecureStorage:' + t)
                if(r) {
                    //Succesful result...
                    ToastHandler.displayNormalMessage('Account Created!');
                } else {
                    //Error...
                    ToastHandler.displayErrorMessage('Could not Create Account');
                }

                //Then navigate to login screen...

            } else {
                ToastHandler.displayErrorMessage('Passwords do not Match')
            }
        } else {
            ToastHandler.displayErrorMessage('Please Fill in all Fields');
        }
    }

This is my create user method.

static createUser(e, p, f, l) {
    result = '';
    axios.post((GRAPHQL_END_POINT), {
      query: print(Queries.CREATE_USER),
      variables: {
        firstName: f,
        lastName: l,
        email: e,
        password: p
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        this.result = res.data.data.createUser.jwt;
        console.log(this.result);
        return true;
        // console.log(this.result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return false;
      })
      // return this.result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the at `saveUserToken()`. If it is async, make sure it waits for the result before returning it.

Comment: saveUserToken is currently not async but I think it should be.  Whenever I make it async I cannot build the app and get a SyntaxError with Unexpected Token.

Comment: What is the expected return of saveUserToken?

Answer (score 0):

You should try making createUser async so you don't mix promises with async syntax.

```
    async createUser(e, p, f, l) {
    const res = await axios.post((GRAPHQL_END_POINT), {
      query: print(Queries.CREATE_USER),
      variables: {
        firstName: f,
        lastName: l,
        email: e,
        password: p
      }
    })
    console.log('res', res)
    return res.data.data.createUser.jwt;
  }
```

Comment: I get the same error as the other answer.  I cannot build.  I dont think it likes Async functions calling other async functions.  I think I need to do something with promises but I have no clue how to write those.